# Web.config - multiple values for setting

Tags: asp.net, web-config

Given below is the web.config file of an existing asp.net web service program (.asmx file)

The following code sets the value of TEST as EEE.

```
     <setting name="TEST" serializeAs="String">
       <value>EEEE</value>
      </setting>
```

This is accccessed from the code using

TESTIntegrationWS.Properties.Settings.Default.TEST

**How do I set multiple values for the the name "TEST" and access it from the code?**

**Web.config file**

```
<?xml version="1.0" ?>
<configuration>
    <configSections>
        <sectionGroup name="applicationSettings" type="System.Configuration.ApplicationSettingsGroup, System, Version=2.0.0.0,             Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089">
            <section name="TESTIntegrationWS.Properties.Settings" type="System.Configuration.ClientSettingsSection, System, Version=2.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089"
            requirePermission="false" />
        </sectionGroup>
    </configSections>
    <applicationSettings>
        <TESTIntegrationWS.Properties.Settings>
            <setting name="TEST" serializeAs="String">
                <value>EEEE</value>
            </setting>
            <system.web>
                <compilation debug="true" targetFramework="4.0" />
            </system.web>
        </TESTIntegrationWS.Properties.Settings>
    </applicationSettings>
    <system.web>
        <compilation debug="true" />
    </system.web>
</configuration>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to assign multiple value to TEST then you can use some separator that is not expected in the value may be comma or semi-colon and in code you can use split to get array of values.